# Are Susan and the Master related?

Tags: doctor-who

I have been wondering if Susan Foreman and the Master are related. Ever since the Missy said she had a daughter it made me think that it's possible that the daughter is Susan's mother. In one of the Doctor Who Novels the Doctor hints that his son is Susan's father.

Now I'm not just basing this on just hints, I also think my theory is possible when you look at their hair color. Nearly every incarnation of the Master has black hair and light skin and Susan shares both of those features.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? which relation do you think is there between the Master and Susan Foreman? Father Daughter? Because you mention the Master and Missy.

Comment: Based on the question as it stands now, the Master (including his "Missy" incarnation) would be Susan's other grandfather (or, possibly, grandmother). The question implies that the Doctor is one of Susan's paternal grandparents, and the Master one of her maternal grandparents.

Comment: There are some references as well to the Doctor "kidnapping" the presidents daughter - by Missy if I recall.  This suggests a possibility that either the Master or the Doctor's progeny rose to the rank of President of the Time Lords.  Or it was a lie (as I recall, Missy mentioned 3 things that the Doctor did and one of them was a lie...)

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - Of course, *The Doctor* was the President of Gallifrey for a while....

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - "There are some references as well to the Doctor "kidnapping" the presidents daughter" ... I don't believe there is anything that confirms this *in canon*, but in the audio stories, Romana is from a well connected family that has produced at least some presidents (including Romana herself), so that could be a reference to her.

Answer (score 3):

**Signs point to "possibly"**, based on an assumption we must make in continuity, and whether or not you take a planned plot point as true.

The exact and complete relationship between The Doctor and The Master has never been revealed.  They've clearly known each other for a long time.  Stories in the novels and audio plays have described an organization called [The Deca](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Deca), of which they were both members.

Now, there's a (somewhat apocryphal) claim that they'd originally planned to reveal that [The Master was The Doctor's brother](https://www.inverse.com/article/22195-doctor-master-siblings-doctor-who). Roger Delgado died, and they chose not to do any more Master stories. By the time The Deadly Assassin came along, the idea had dropped off the table.

If we assume that Susan is indeed The Doctor's granddaughter (There's some argument about that as well), and that the planned revelation was true, that would make Susan the grand-niece of The Master.

That's a lot of assumptions, but it's a fairly good guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Factors *could* point to yes, but there's nothing concrete**

- *But*, it has to be said: Appearance isn't a good indicating factor of relation when it comes to Gallifreyans,  with regeneration coming into play. If anything, the fact that Susan was apparently far more telepathically strong than average -  with her being even more susceptible to Psychic attacks than her grandfather too as a result  ("Edge of Destruction" episode" - you can also see her just regularly using telepathy in the "Sensorites" episode) - *could* serve as evidence with the Master *also* being shown to be stronger than average.
- What we *do* know: Her father is listed as "Pandad VII" - President of Gallifrey, which is also backed up by episode "Hell Bent" citing her father as having been that (president, albeit without giving the name. Book "A Brief History of Time Lords" also alludes to this). The Audio "Disassembled" seemed to imply he *was* the Doctor's offspring too, with him refusing to have Susan *or* the Doctor killed for fleeing the planet. Nothing however, is canonically listed on her mother other than her having had one - leaving the possibility open that it very well *could* have been Missy's daughter, as the question seems to ask.
- What we also *do* know: The Doctor certainly *knew* the daughter which would suggest a closeness was maintained between his and the Master's respective families - with him having even gifted the Dark Star Alloy broach when something significant happened related to the daughter ("The Witch's Familiar").

As for now, it's all just various dots that could be connected and speculation - perhaps more details will come, but for now, sorry for not having been able to give anything more concrete/a yes or no.